# How to plot a two-dimensional chart with a boolean attribute defining colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have the following DataFrame:

LATITUDE  LONGITUDE  STATE

...   ...   True

With the code bellow I can plot the graph with coordinates

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x=df['LAT'], y=df['LONG'])
plt.show()
```

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DNG4.png)

However, I want to define two different colors for each point according to the 'state' attribute

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `c` parameter, taking your example and adding the `STATUS` column

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = {'LAT': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'LONG': [3, 2, 4, 5, 3], 'STATUS': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1] }

plt.scatter(x=df['LAT'], y=df['LONG'], c=df['STATUS'])
plt.show()
```

it shows a bicoloured chart

[image: Chart with two colours]